# Object doesn't support property or method 'set' in microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, microsoft-edge

this code doesn't work in Microsoft Edge:

```
let formdata = new FormData;
formdata.set('name', this.form.name);
```

error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'set'

description: "Object doesn't support property or method 'set'"
message: "Object doesn't support property or method 'set'"
number: -2146827850
stack: "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'set' at l.methods.sendData
```

Comment: did you mean `new FormData()` instead of `new FormData`?

Comment: That is because Edge doesn't support the `set` method of `FormData`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set.

Comment: Please create a new FormData object and use `.append` instead of `.set`.

Comment: @Ahmad That makes no difference at all

Comment: @Ahmad One could omit '()'. `console.log(new Array)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks